# SQL idea for a query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function

I have this kind of table

```
ID-----CategoryID-----Price

1---------1-----------200

2---------1-----------300

3---------2-----------150

4---------2-----------100
```

I need a SQL query where I can get average of elements by Category ID. The results should be like:

```
CategoryID----------AVG_Price

1-------------------250

2-------------------175
```

I have not been able to think it through..

Comment: `SELECT categoryID, AVG(Price) AVGPrice FROM tableName GROUP BY CategoryID` -- try that.

Comment: oops, I didn't see you were commenting and answered it, my bad @491243

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I completely forgot Group By outta' my mind. :P

Answer (score 3):

```
Select categoryid, avg(price)
from table
group by categoryid
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL backticks aren't required, but are used if your field names contain spaces or reserved words:

```
SELECT   `CategoryID`, avg(`Price`) as `AVG_Price`
FROM     `tablename`
GROUP BY `CategoryID`;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac805/2)

---

***Note:** Category 2 averages to `125` not `175` (`150+100=250; 250/2=125`)*